# Invalid self-signed certificate

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, certificate, browser-sync

I'm trying and failing to create a self-signed certificate. What I'm trying to achieve is to test a webpage with webworker on my mobile and for this I do need https. But for the time being I'm trying to run it locally on my pc.

I'm using openssl on Windows (I'm using v1.1.0 light version from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)).

I'm installing CA certificate on my machine and I'm serving the page with browser-sync https options providing cert and key.

Error I'm getting is NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID. What may be the invalid part?

Commands I'm running:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out CA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key CA.key -sha256 -days 182 -out CA.pem -config ca.cfg
openssl x509 -outform der -in CA.pem -out CA.crt
openssl genrsa -out dev.key 2048
openssl req -new -key dev.key -out dev.csr -config dev.cfg
openssl x509 -req -in dev.csr -CA CA.pem -CAkey CA.key -CAcreateserial -out dev.crt -days 1825 -sha256 -extfile dev.ext
openssl pkcs12 -export -in dev.crt -inkey dev.key -out dev.p12
```

CA.cfg:

```
[ req ]

default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_ext
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only

[ subject ]

countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default         = PL

stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = PL

localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = PL

organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Example Organization

commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default          = Example Division

emailAddress                = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer

keyUsage               = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName         = @alternate_names

[ req_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier = hash

keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName       = @alternate_names

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = 192.168.0.17
```

dev.cfg

```
[ req ]

default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_ext
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only

[ subject ]

countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default         = PL

stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = PL

localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = PL

organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Example Organization

commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default          = Example Division

emailAddress                = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer

keyUsage               = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName         = @alternate_names

[ req_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier = hash

keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName       = @alternate_names

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = 192.168.0.17
```

dev.ext:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = 192.168.0.17
```

Comment: You're getting the error on desktop or mobile ?

Comment: `DNS.1 = 192.168.0.17` - an IP address is not a hostname. Use `IP.1` instead. And I don't see you using a useful CN either. Apart from that it is not clear how you intend to use the certificate, i.e. what is the URL you use when accessing the server?

Comment: I've changed to IP.1, thanks for it. Sadly I'm still getting 'invalid' error. I'm getting this error on desktop while accessing the page through https://192.168.0.17:3000.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've lost hope to quick with posting this question.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority/21340898#21340898) solution to work.

Providing both dns (localhost) and ip (e.g. 192.168.0.17) works on the Windows machine.